# php tags are not working/ string not displaying

Tags: php, html

I am trying to program in PHP, but php tags are not working:
and i believe there's no error in my code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php 
            $test = "Gumagana ako :P";
            echo "$test";
        ?>
        <title>My First PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        My Test String is <?php echo $test; ">
    </body>
</html>
```

What do you think is the problem? FYI, I'm using xampp.

Comment: where are you running this? did u install a local php server to try that out?

Comment: you have to add closing tag ?> like My Test String is <?php echo $test; ?>

Comment: 10 questions with no accepted answers isn't good. Please go back over your other questions and accept any answers that helped you.

Comment: @Onheiron yes I have a local php server apache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your file extension is .php and its inside your htdocs folder of Xampp folder. And also make sure, Apache service is running fine.

And also make sure, you are browsing this like `http://localhost/yourfile.php`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php 
            $test = "Gumagana ako :P";
            echo "$test";
        ?>
        <title>My First PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        My Test String is <?php echo $test; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I modified my index.php and still my test string is not showing.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes so what was the problem? if it is not solved then why have you accepted the answer??

Comment: Make sure your Apache service is running fine. Also make sure, you have changed the extension but not renamed the file name. Are you sure its file name is not index.php.html

Answer (score 3):

You made a typo in closing your php.

```
My Test String is <?php echo $test; ">
```

Close your php like this:

```
My Test String is <?php echo $test; ?>
```

Otherwise php tries to interpret the following as php which gives an error:

```
"> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Yes I changed it now. But i still got no string output on my website.

Comment: the php you asked for is valid, it has something to do with your server configuration check your error log with the terminal/commandline tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing PHP closing tag or the question has been replaced with a double quote :

```
 My Test String is <?php echo $test; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`My Test String is <?php echo $test; ?>` //tag was not closed

Answer (score 1):

```
  <body>


       My Test String is <?php echo $test; ">


  </body>
```

there is misteck

```
My Test String is <?php echo $test; ?>
```

please check it

Comment: I changed it now. But only blank space displayed

Answer (score 1):

Just Write like this : -

```
My Test String is <?php echo $test;?>
```

Comment: I changed it now. It still is the same.

Comment: can u tell me what u want to do ??

Comment: I want to view My Test String Gumagana ako :P

Comment: <body>

         $test="abc";
       My Test String is <?php echo $test; ?>


  </body>